# make REST call with typescript

Tags: rest, angular, typescript-typings

I installed the "sb admin  2" dashboard with html5/angular2.
This sample works with typescript. To instanciate charts, the file charts.compenent.ts defines the class and then defines the charts attributes and data as follows

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'chart-cmp',
    templateUrl: 'chart.component.html'
})

export class ChartComponent implements OnInit {
    ngOnInit() {

        var container:any = $('#container');
        container.highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'area'
            },
...................................
```

In my case, I want to get the date from a restfull service.

Can you help me to do this please?? 
any input will help

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the correct imports,

```
import {Http, Response, URLSearchParams}                                         from '@angular/http';
```

This is how to make a get request,

**Get Request**

```
        saveProfile(model: Profile, isValid: boolean) {
                let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
// set params to go to URL
                params.set('email', model.email);
                params.set('first_name', model.first_name);

                return this.http.get('url/path/here/dont/forget/port',
                    { search: params })
                    .map((res: Response) => res.json())
                    .subscribe((res) => {
                        console.log(res);
    // Map the values in the response to useable variables
                        this.auth.user.email = res.user.email;
                        this.auth.user.first_name = res.user.first_name;
                    });
            }
        }
```

**Post Request**

How to make a post request,This is a popular post request used in the auth0 library. You can find that [here](https://github.com/auth0-blog/angular2-http)

```
authenticate(username, password) {

  let creds = JSON.stringify({ username: username.value, password: password.value });

  let headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

  this.http.post('http://localhost:3001/sessions/create', creds, {
    headers: headers
    })
    .subscribe(
      data => {
        this.saveJwt(data.json().id_token);
        username.value = null;
        password.value = null;
      },
      err => this.logError(err.json().message),
      () => console.log('Authentication Complete')
    );
  }
```

These examples will get a response from the server. If you want to do some more technical things like get the new data to update in the view, you will have to create an `observable`. If I were you I would get this down then when you need to understand `observable` you can incorporate that.